# Sequence of letters of the form abcba

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A sequence of letters of the form abcba in which the sequence is unchanged upon reversing
the order is called a palindrome. How many 5 letter palindromes are there if we are allowed to repeat letters more than twice?

When i tried to do this problem out i thought would use the multiplication rule and say 26 factorial but i am having a hard time thinking of a way to meet all of the qualifications of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  if you choose the first letter, you know the last one.  How many letters can you choose?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would just be 26*26*26. You have 26 letters for the 'a', 26 for 'b', and 26 for 'c'. Because you can repeat letters more than twice, a factorial wouldn't work, because you'd be removing a letter you could use for both of the other spots. 
So, 26*26*26=17576.

Answer (score 0):

We are interested in 5-letter palindromes.  Presumably the alphabet we use will be the standard $26$-letter alphabet: "A,B,C,D,...,Z"

We have that they will be of the form:

$$\underline{\color{red}{\bullet}}~\underline{\color{blue}{\bullet}}~\underline{\color{green}{\bullet}}~\underline{\color{blue}{\bullet}}~\underline{\color{red}{\bullet}}$$

Since it is a palindrome, we know that the first character must be the same as the last character.  Similarly the second character must be the same as the fourth character.  (*as suggested by my coloring scheme above*)

Break this up via multiplication principle.

- How many ways can you choose the letter used for the red location above?
- How many ways can you choose the letter used for the blue location above?
- How many ways can you choose the letter used for the green location above?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite obvious. As you can repeat a letter more than twice, the answer is $26^3$. In general, for $n$ letter palindromes, the expression would be $26^{\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \rfloor}$.